# What is SAS format 8.

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and currently working on a small piece of work with SAS.

Could I please ask what the below format means? I believe the 8. is formatting two digits to the right of the decimal place such as 896.33 but I am not sure. Not really sure what input means.

input(tablename.fieldname, 8.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an INFORMAT, not a FORMAT. It means to read the first 8 characters as a number. If there is a decimal point in the data then it is used naturally. You could have up to 7 digits to the right of the decimal point (since the decimal point would use up the eighth character position).  It will also support reading scientific notation so '896.33E2' would mean the number 89,633.